# Set Dates beyond current year using Ionic Framework Date Picker

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am working on a project where users can input their certificates which have expiration dates. I'm using ionic datepicker which works great for the completion date of earning the certificate but I run into an issue with choosing the expiration date. The datepicker won't go passed 2020 for year option. For example - if a user has a certificate that expires in 2022. Is there a way to add future years to the scroll option? This is my current code:

```
    <ion-datetime display-format="MM/DD/YYYY" picker-format="MM DD YYYY" type="date" formControlName="dateExpired"
        type="text">
    </ion-datetime>
```

Answer (score 2):

it looks like you can set a min or max date [take a look at this link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime).

Answer (score 1):

**Min and Max Datetimes** - https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime#min-and-max-datetimes

> Dates are infinite in either direction, so for a user's selection
>   there should be at least some form of restricting the dates that can
>   be selected. **By default, the maximum date is to the end of the current
>   year**, and the minimum date is from the beginning of the year that was
>   100 years ago.
>
> **To customize the minimum and maximum datetime values, the min and max
>   component properties can be provided** which may make more sense for the
>   app's use-case, rather than the default of the last 100 years.
>   Following the same IS0 8601 format listed in the table above, each
>   component can restrict which dates can be selected by the user. By
>   passing 2016 to the min property and 2020-10-31 to the max property,
>   the datetime will restrict the date selection between the beginning of
>   2016, and October 31st of 2020.

Example:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label position="stacked">Date</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime display-format="MM/DD/YYYY" picker-format="MM DD YYYY" min="2016" max="2020-10-31"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```